# Who was the British liaison officer shunned by French colleagues in 1918 France?

Tags: world-war-one

I seem to recall reading that during the German offensive of March 1918, the British retreat led to many Frenchmen suspecting that Britain was about to abandon them.

Most particularly, I'm sure I read somewhere that a young British liaison officer,  at this time, found himself shunned by his French colleagues, and was rather upset about it. Does anyone recall reading this, and if so where? I haven't been able to find it again.